$\lim_{x\to0}\frac1{x^2}$
My teacher explained in class that the limit $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac1{x^2}$$ is controversial since there are $2$ views regarding this:

Even though the $RHL$ and the $LHL$ are both $+\infty$, $x$ can approach $0$ from the right and the left at $2$ different 'rates' or in other words both the infinities obtained are incomparable, so they may not be the same. So, the given limit does not exist.
If $x$ approaches $0$ from the right and the left at the same 'rate', then $RHL=LHL$, so the value of the given limit is $+\infty$.

Which of these thought processes is correct? Any help or ideas would be highly appreciated.

I never heard a single mathematitian that held the first view.

The limit is $\infty$. There should be  no controversies.

There is no controversy here if you just use the actual definition of what it means to have limit $\infty$. It is very straightforward to prove from this that the limit is $\infty$. This is not something that's just a matter of opinion.

The limit "does not exist", but the reason is just that the convention in a calculus class is to say "the limit does not exist" when you would also write "$\cdots=\infty$" since $\infty$ is not a real number so we don't have a real number limit.

Those who have doubts or require any clarification can ask for details before voting to close this question. The question presents 2 possible ways to evaluate $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac1{x^2}$ and asks which approach is correct. If any of those who voted to close the question can kindly elaborate how the question focuses on multiple problems, it would be helpful.

Kindly raise any issues or confusions regarding this question in the comments before downvoting.

@5xum But according to the answers in this question, $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x \ dx$ diverges instead of equaling zero because the endpoints of the integral approach $| \infty|$ at different rates. If that reasoning is valid there, then why isn't it valid here to think that the two sides of the limit approach $x=0$ at different rates?

@YvesDaoust then what about the example that VV_721 gave?

@YvesDaoust rate here means how fast $x\to0$. So, if $x\to0^+$ faster than $x\to0^-$, the sequence of values obtained by letting $x$ assume values from a sequence tending to $0$ for the RHL become greater than the LHL in magnitude.

@YvesDaoust I am not acquainted with the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of a limit since I am in high school. Also, this concept of rate for infinite limits was mentioned by my teacher only when this limit was being discussed.

@VV_721 Yes, the integral you rote diverges, because if you apply the definitions of integrals over infinite intervals, the definition tells you that the integral diverges. Similarly, if you apply the definition of $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to a} f(x)=\infty$ onto the OP's question, it turns out the definition does apply. These are two separate cases, I don't know why you expect them to have the same result...

@5xum so basically when working with infinity we have to keep in mind the definitions of what it means for something to be infinity?

@MathGuy when doing mathematics, you always need to keep in mind the definitions. In a sense, that's all that mathematics is. It's definitions, rules for manipulating statements, and then asking questions about the truthfulness of certain statements.

The definition is as follows:

Let $f$ be a function defined on an open set containing the set $(a-\epsilon, a)\cup(a,a+\epsilon)$ for some $\epsilon > 0$. Then, we say $$\lim_{x\to a} f(x)=\infty$$ if and only if, for every $M\in \mathbb R$, there exists some $\delta > 0$ such that, for all $x$ for which $|x-a|<\delta$, we have $f(x)>M$. Symbollycally, this is written as:
$$\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=\infty\iff \forall M\in\mathbb R\exists \delta > 0\forall x\in\mathbb R: |x-\delta|<0 \implies f(x)>M$$

This definition, or an equivalent formulation of it, can be found in any introductory textbook on calculus.
By this definition, $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac 1{x^2} = \infty$$ is a relatively easy to prove fact.

What you wrote is true, but I think this answer would be improved by confirming that even though the limit $=\infty$ by any standard definition, it's also true that most calculus books would say that the limit "does not exist", albeit not for the reason the OP's teacher proposed.

@MarkS. , so this means that if a limit is $\infty$, the function in the limit can be made greater than any arbitrary real number for $x$ close but not equal to the value to be approached. Alternatively, the limit can be said to not exist in the set of real numbers. Am I right?

@RakshithPL Yes, both of those are true.

@MarkS. , thank you for confirming! I am more clear about infinite limits now.
